# How can i handel exception of java -cp command in shell script(.sh file)

Tags: java, bash, shell

I put this command in .sh file:

```
CP="$1"
"$JAVA_CMD" -cp "$CP" "$MAIN_CLASS" "$@"
```

Where CP is the path of the jar file

my problem is:

when CP does not have proper value, and in this instruction it could not  find the main class and i will receive this exception:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError
```

how can i handle this exception in shell script?

Comment: There's no such thing as "handling exception" in shell script. You can (and can only) inspect the exit status of commands in the shell, and then decide what you want to do. But what do you want to do exactly? If you want to handle the "Java exception", then NO, sorry, Bash is another language, and it can't dig into your JVM.

Comment: Thanks, i would like check the exit status of command and show my message instead of java command exception, is it possible?

Comment: Yes, see JohnH's answer.

Comment: Uh you also want to show a custom message. I'll write an answer real quick.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

To replace any error printed to stderr with your own error message, you can suppress your command's stderr (by redirecting to `/dev/null`) and print your message instead when your command's exit status is nonzero:

```
CP="$1"
"$JAVA_CMD" -cp "$CP" "$MAIN_CLASS" "$@" 2>/dev/null || { echo "error: Java exited with nonzero status $?"; exit 1; }
```

A more verbose way to do this, which is probably more readable to folks relatively new to Bash:

```
CP="$1"
if ! "$JAVA_CMD" -cp "$CP" "$MAIN_CLASS" "$@" 2>/dev/null; then
    echo "error: Java exited with nonzero status $?"
    exit 1
fi
```

Comment: Great, Thank you so much, I put it in my code and now it works as well,  Regards

Comment: @faribafarrokhpour No problem. You may accept the answer by clicking the check mark below the arrows on the left to mark the problem as solved.

Comment: Thanks, I have just did that

Answer (score 1):

Perhaps you may find this link helpful: http://www.tldp.org/LDP/abs/html/exit-status.html

Bash contains a built-in variable called `$?` that contains the exit code of the previously executed command. `$? == 0` means the Java program has been executed successfully, and `$? != 0` means the Java program threw an exception such as the one in your case.

Comment: thanks, i changed the script like this # Run tool with classpath ($1) and other arguments
function run_tool(){
    CP="$1" ; shift
   "$JAVA_CMD" -cp "$CP" "$MAIN_CLASS" "$@"
   if [ "$?" != 0 ]
   then
     echo "class path is not correct"
   fi
}   but i have receive class not found excedption and also my message

Comment: I want to show my message instead of class not found exception